# getElementById with an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, wordpress

I'm modifying a plugin of wordpress and I have a little problem. When I search in an array an id, the console returns me that form[0].getElementById is not a function.

That's my code.

```
var form = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-body");
var i=0;
while (i<(form.length)) { 
    var tag = form[i].getElementById("em-booking"); 
    if(tag) { 
        var carles = form[i].getElementById("formulari-cemcat");
        carles.style.display = "none";
    } 
    i++; 
}
```

Maybe someone can help me and look up my problem.

Thank You so much,

Carles

Comment: one which line it is giving an error?

Comment: Can you post your HTML code?

Comment: The one who downvoted should really explain why. What's wrong with a newbie question like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`getElementById` is only defined on `document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). There is no need to be able to call it on an element, since IDs are supposed to be unique throughout the document.

Having multiple elements with the same ID inside a document is invalid.

If you really have multiple elements with the same ID, you should fix that and use classes instead. Then you can do:

```
var tag = form[i].querySelector(".em-booking");
```

---

FYI, `form` is a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not an array.